# Why do jdk need to use "final" to create object of "Semaphore"?

Tags: java

[image]

Is it an object of "Semaphore" that does not need to be changed?

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  1) It makes it impossible to cut-and-paste it.  2) The image link is liable to break, rendering your question meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the `available` field as `final` ensures that the value of the field will be visible to all threads without any other synchronization.  This is *necessary* because you have two methods (`getItem` and `putItem`) that use that field without any synchronization.

If the `final` is omitted, then is is possible that some threads might see the pre-initialized value of `available` (i.e. `null`) and get an NPE in their first call to the `getItem` method.

(By design or by accident, this is not a problem in the `putItem` method.  There you are calling `markAsUsed` before accessing `available`.  The `markAsUsed` method synchronizes on `this` which should provide the required *happens-before* to guarantee that the thread then sees the proper `available` value.)

---

It is worth noting that it is (generally) good practice to declare fields that should never change as `final`.  If nothing else, this documents your *intent*.